# LOAD DATA exponentially slows down when table has indexes

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, mysql-5.7

I'm using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` to populate a table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `player_talent` (
  `player_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `talent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `level` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`player_id`,`level`),
  KEY `player_talent_talent_id_foreign` (`talent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `player_talent_player_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`player_id`) REFERENCES `players` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `player_talent_talent_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`talent_id`) REFERENCES `talents` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I'm using MySQL 5.7 on a Google cloud and before import I disable binlog and set `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`, `unique_checks`, and `foreign_key_checks` to 0

Here's how used storage space looks like when I load data:

[image: index]

IOPS are consistently sitting at maximum. On the above image import didn't even finish. If I drop all indexes and then recreate them after import here's how this graph looks like:

[image: no-index]

Import stage has a consistent linear performance. Recreating indexes takes longer than import, but at least it finishes in a reasonable time.

It there a way to avoid doing that manually? I thought that `LOAD DATA` is supposed to provide the best possible performance. `DISABLE KEYS` is not supported for InnoDB

Comment: How many rows are in the files that you are importing?

Comment: How much memory does your instance have? You can also try pre-sorting the import file by primary key, if it's not already.

Comment: @IkeWalker around 250M rows

Comment: @Vadim 8Gb memory, 2 cores. I exported data using `SELECT * INTO OUTFILE` so I believe it is already sorted by primary key, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Ike's advice below is very good, but you can also try increasing the tier size (memory) for the duration of the import to reduce the amount of data that needs to be read back from disk as it looks like the data set might be larger than the amount of memory on the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have 250M rows, which is a lot to ask MySQL to insert in a single statement. To improve ingestion performance, I recommend that you split your input into multiple files.

I [blogged](http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2014/12/12/loading-large-flat-files-into-mysql-with-load-data-infile-and-pt-fifo-split/) about this problem in the past, and some shortcuts to make it easier to break the file into smaller pieces. I'd say each file should be 1 million rows or smaller.

You can also find other good suggestions [here](http://derwiki.tumblr.com/post/24490758395/loading-half-a-billion-rows-into-mysql) and [here](https://dbahire.com/testing-the-fastest-way-to-import-a-table-into-mysql-and-some-interesting-5-7-performance-results/) for tuning MySQL to improve bulk import performance.